# Convert QHostAddress to QUrl

Tags: qt

There is a `QHostAddress`. How to extract a string representation of an IP address from it without dealing directly with the IPv4/IPv6 addresses?

`QHostAddress::toString()` for the localhost gives `::ffff:127.0.0.1` which isn't usable as `http://::ffff:127.0.0.1`.

Comment: If you want to use the IPv6 address in an url, just enclose it in scare brackets. `http://[::ffff:127.0.0.1]` works fine for me in e.g. Firefox. [further info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Literal_IPv6_addresses_in_network_resource_identifiers)

Comment: @KarstenKoop, yes, I've seen that. The question is about avoiding dealing with this.

Comment: Did you try using `QUrl::setHost` with the returned string?